# How to bring my text up a bit more to center align with the grid image on the left?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

How can I bring this textbox up so I can center align it with the grid image on the left? I've tried using a padding and translate function but it does nothing at all. What can I do so I can have this center aligned? Thanks for the help!

```css
.sub-header{
    margin:100px
}
.container-header{
    padding: 2px;
}
.sub-header-image{
    display: grid;
}
#image2{
    grid-column: 2/ span 2;
    grid-row: 1 / span 2;
}
#image1{
    grid-column: 1 / span 3;
    grid-row: 2 / span 2;
}
.sub-header-image img{
    height: 300px;
    width: 475px;
}
.subheader-text{
    display:block;
    margin-left: auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 40%;
}
.subheader-text h1{
    font-size: 30px;
}
.subheader-text p{
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
 <section class="sub-header">
        <div class="container-sub-header">
            <div class="sub-header-image">
                <img id="image2" src="Images/shutterstock_388910350.jpg">
                <img id="image1" src="Images/Cedar_Creek_Abbey_Island_Ruby_Beach.jpeg">
            </div>
            <div class="subheader-text">
                <h1>A State for City Life and Outdoor Adventure</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod                       tempor incididunt ut 
                    labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud                         exercitation ullamco laboris 
                    nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in  
                    esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat  
                    culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the below CSS to fix this

```css
sub-header{
    margin:100px
}
.container-header{
    padding: 2px;
}
.container-sub-header{
  display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.sub-header-image{
    display: grid;
    width: 70%;
}
#image2{
    grid-column: 2/ span 2;
    grid-row: 1 / span 2;
}
#image1{
    grid-column: 1 / span 3;
    grid-row: 2 / span 2;
}
.sub-header-image img{
    height: 300px;
    width: 475px;
}
.subheader-text{
    margin-left: auto;
    text-align: center;
    width:30%;
}

.subheader-text h1{
    font-size: 30px;
}
.subheader-text p{
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<section class="sub-header">
        <div class="container-sub-header">
            <div class="sub-header-image">
                <img id="image2" src="Images/shutterstock_388910350.jpg">
                <img id="image1" src="Images/Cedar_Creek_Abbey_Island_Ruby_Beach.jpeg">
            </div>
            <div class="subheader-text">
                <h1>A State for City Life and Outdoor Adventure</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod                       tempor incididunt ut 
                    labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud                         exercitation ullamco laboris 
                    nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in  
                    esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat  
                    culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```